# Minecraft PE won't show itself after purchase

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Two years ago I purchased Minecraft PE. I have not used it frequently since 2014. I purchased it on my tablet in Google Play, but when I got to Apps > All the only thing showing is a Minecraft PE Demo. I installed the demo prior to purchase. I'm 100% certain that I used the same account, but I can not get Minecraft PE to show up. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

- Double check "Apps on the cloud"
- Go to the MC:PE app page and see if it says "Buy" or "Install"
- Contact Google Play Support

There probably isn't anything you can do if it's a purchase problem.